# Can I access values from one part of a Yup schema within another?

Tags: javascript, validation, schema, yup

I have a Yup validation schema for a quiz application, where I define two separate parts: questions and results. Each part has its own validation rules. Is there a way to access the values from the questions part within the .test() function of the results part? I need to perform validation in the results section based on aggregated data from the questions section.

Here's a simplified version of my schema structure:

```
const quizSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    questions: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.object().shape({
            // ... question validation rules
        })
    ),
    results: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.object().shape({
            // ... result validation rules
            .test(
                'covers-all-values',
                'The first result should cover the minimum possible point total from all choices.',
                (value, context) => {
                    // How can I access values from the "questions" part here?
                    // ...
                }
            ),
        })
    ),
});
```

Any insights on how to reference values from the questions array within the .test() function of the results array would be greatly appreciated.